# Binding a List of internal object to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, access-modifiers

I need to bind a list of object of a class that I need to be `internal` since it will never ever be used outside of this .cs file.

```
internal class DataGridViewItems
{
    internal string Id{ get; set; }
    internal string Description{ get; set; }
    internal double Value{ get; set; }
    internal string Reference {get;set;}
};
```

Is there a way to bind this to a `DataGridView`? It only works if I put everything to `Public`

Comment: Simple: You *don't* need it to be `internal`. You need it to be `public`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me this ? Why does it need to be public ?

Comment: You need it to be public because "It only works if I put everything to public". Therefore, if you need it to work, you need it to be public.

Comment: Ok, I guess. So...is there a reason why datagridview doesn't seems to work with the internal modifiers ?

Comment: Because they wrote the code that way.

Comment: Note that you can make the _class_ internal and the _properties_ public - that way the `DataGridView` can still use reflection to get the public properties and bind to those.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to bind this to a DataGridView?

Sure - make the *class* `internal` but make the *properties* `public`.  That way `DataGridView` will still find the public properties through reflection when it creates/binds the columns, but the class won't be directly accessible outside of the assembly.

> I need to be internal since it will never ever be used outside of this .cs file.

Note that `internal` makes the class visible to all types within the same *assembly*, not just that CS file.  It sounds like what you want is a class that's private to the class that's creating/using it:

```
public class MyView
{
    private class DataGridViewItems
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public double Value{ get; set; }
        public string Reference {get;set;}
    };
}
```

Comment: Setting the  property accessor is never used". I don't thing that's an issue though.class as Private works but Resharper gives me an advise on get property with "Auto-implemented